# Как можно сохранить в базу данных firebase auth данные пользователя

Tags: javascript, firebase

Есть приложение, которое считает статистику, необходимо эту статистику привязать к аккаунту,
дабы при смене аккаунта она подругажалась на особой странице.

Авторизация реализована на google firebase.
Каким образом можно реализовать задумку?